# IR Receiver for Android Device

Tags: remote-control

Assuming I already have a USB IR receiver and WMC remote as well as an Android device with a USB port, what is the best way to go about controlling the Android device with the remote after plugging in the receiver?

Comment: Welcome to [android.se] As you can see in [faq], which app does *x* is outta scope

Comment: @Sid: I'm more interested in presence *at all* rather than choosing between one of several apps.

Comment: This question is fine. @Ignacio: We have a strong tendency to dislike app recommendation questions here. You might do better to phrase your question as a problem to be solved rather than an app to be found.

Comment: @AlEverett: I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Looks perfect to me! I'm very curious for the answer, it's an interesting question! A pity that our devices have no built-in IR, there would be plenty of uses for it.

Comment: will the IR blaster be reconized by android out of the box ? if your device doesn't have support for it in it's kernel but here you go start with this there is easy may to do this but here you can start from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JEvM7gvcNE you can follow the guide to build your own IR then use Asmart remote from the play store to control it

Comment: this is an other way too http://www.irdroid.com/purchase/

Comment: I'm looking for a way to use a *receiver*, not a blaster.

Comment: sorry ,I must have miss understodod ,the best way to do it ,is via the kernel but it is not gonna be an easy ride ,but not impossible ,create a new input device that's all it take ,then make an app that can use that new input device