# Remote control my android

Tags: remote-control

I have an ICS tablet with HDMI output. I want to use it as a media center connected to my TV, but it would be ideal if I could control it without having to go back and forth from the couch. I have a laptop and an android phone. I'm looking for suggestions on how to control the tablet remotely.

My ideal usage is being able to play videos, pause, select new media, watch online videos (youtube, vimeo, etc) and listen to music (hype machine, soundcloud, bandcamp, etc), as well as use music and video apps.

Comment: I know I can use a really long HDMI cable, but that's 1) expensive, and 2) not cableless enough

Comment: Would it be a solution to use some UPnP server on your tablet, like e.g. [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp)? If your TV supports that, you then could use the TV's RC to control it.

Comment: @Izzy, I think it's not my case, I have a LG LM3400 (no UPnP / DLNA), but you can post your comment as an answer, it will surely benefit others!

Comment: Sorry to read that it won't work for you. But as you suggested, I made it an answer so at least others might profit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Many recent TV devices ship with [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Living_Network_Alliance) support. If yours does, you could turn your tablet into an [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upnp) server using an app like e.g. [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp). Once that app is up and running, it serves the tablet's contents to your TV. Your TV detects accesses this service, and you can control it using the TV's remote control:

> BubbleUPnP is a full featured UPnP/DLNA Control Point, UPnP Media Renderer and UPnP Media Server. Play easily your music, videos and images on your phone and devices on your network (DLNA TVs, XBMC, WMP, ...), from your external UPnP Media Servers. Play your phone/tablet media to those devices.
>   Browse and play your local phone/tablet and cloud media from other devices [...]

So basically, this works both directions -- and you can even use this app to browse contents of your other UPnP sources on the tablet itself.

Comment: Sounds awesome (too bad I can't test it). Does it works only for acessing media (such as video files, mp3 audio, etc at the file system level) or it enables controlling apps as well?

Comment: It's a media server (and client). I've linked the concerning Wikipedia articles for further details; "DLNA" is the article you should start with. It all comes done to the "common denominator" both, client and server, share. For the descibed app that's pictures, music, and videos AFAIK (also see above quote from the apps playstore description). I'm not aware about more being handled -- but of course the client handles media playback & control.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, you could install a VNC server on the tablet and then access it with a VNC client running on another device over wifi. It's a bit overkill, but it will certainly allow you to control it remotely.

Comment: I'm considering this option, but looking for alternatives.

Comment: [Me too.](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47957/36531)